# Does the single-player campaign unlock anything for multiplayer?

Tags: battlefield-4

Will I get any weapons or something usable in multiplayer if I complete Singleplayer? Does Difficulty matter? (Battlefield 3 did unlock something in multiplayer. Or at least co-op did. If I remember clearly.)

It's not like I'm not interested in the story or it's that hard to headshot everyone through the map, but it can be annoying on harder levels. I'm trying to decide if it's worth plaything through the harder difficulties, so knowing what I might get is good to know.

Comment: It will unlock *something*, at least some dog tags.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 6 multiplayer weapons you can unlock through the campaign. You can check them under Assignments -> Single Player Assignments. They are as follows:

```
TOMBSTONE ACTUAL (CAMPAIGN)
AWARD REQUIREMENTS
Complete Baku
REWARD
M412 REX

FANG OF THE UNDERWORLD (CAMPAIGN)
AWARD REQUIREMENTS
Complete Kunlun Mountains
REWARD
SHANK

A TRAPPED WOLF WILL (CAMPAIGN)
AWARD REQUIREMENTS
Complete Tashgar
REWARD
MACHETE

TO VALHALLA (CAMPAIGN)
AWARD REQUIREMENTS
Make the final choice
REWARD
QBZ-95-1

PEACE MAKER (CAMPAIGN)
AWARD REQUIREMENTS
Make the final choice
REWARD
P90

FINAL DUTY (CAMPAIGN)
AWARD REQUIREMENTS
Make the final choice
REWARD
M249
```

*** SPOILER ***

> The last 3 require you to play the final mission 3 times, choosing a different ending each play through: kill Hannah, let the Valkyrie be destroyed, or kill Irish.

Comment: Thank you. I saw these on Battlelog, but I could not decide if they mean Multiplayer, or just singleplayer unlock. (You know, the ammo box stuff.)

Comment: Do you have to play through the entire game again to get the other guns, or can you just play the final mission 3 times?

Comment: @Garrison Neely you can just play the last mission.

Comment: I just restarted the final mission and lost one achievement (the second one). This is the worst form of trolling. Shame on you DICE.

Comment: I just replayed the last mission with a different end choice, and I still only have the gun and the achievement for my first choice... :(

Comment: Nope, got it, just some time had to pass