# Does the singleplayer campaign unlock anything for multiplayer?

Tags: battlefield-1

[Battlefield 4 unlocked multiplayer weapons for completing the campaign mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/141441/218319) — does Battlefield 1 offer any rewards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't unlock any weapons by playing the campaign. You can, however, unlock some skins.

- **C96 – His Lordship** - Complete Through Mud and Blood (Any Difficulty) + Find all Field Manuals & Find all Codex Entries
- **Auto Revolver – Straight Flush** - Complete Friends in High Places (Any Difficulty) + Find all Field Manuals & Find all Codex Entries
- **Cei-Rigotti – Fiamme Ferdi** - Complete Avanti Savoia (Any Difficulty) + Find all Field Manuals & Find all Codex Entries
- **Howdah Pistol – Frontiersman** - Complete The Runner (Any Difficulty) + Find all Field Manuals & Find all Codex Entries
- **Russian 1895 – Desert Dweller** - Complete Nothing is Written (Any Difficulty) + Find all Field Manuals & Find all Codex Entries
- **M1909 – Trench Cleaner** - Complete the Single Player Campaign (Any Difficulty)
- **Landship Tank – Black Bess** - Complete the Single Player Campaign (Any Difficulty) + Find all “Single Player” Field Manuals & Find all “Single Player” Codex Entries

[Source - no weapons](https://www.pcpowerplay.com.au/feature/10-tips-for-battlefield-1,439924)

[Source - skins](http://www.battlefieldcp.com/battlefield-1-campaign-weapon-skin-unlocks-multiplayer/)

Comment: These are skins, please update your answer accordingly. I wonder if there's a single weapon or item unlock?

Comment: @user218319 Added an explanation.

Comment: Cricket bat https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmT-4p-n9Ag